# UPDATE with set field determined conditionally not working?

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have an after insert trigger on a table that is to update fields on another table based on the newly inserted row. (Its deducting stock qty in one location and adding to another location. Each column is a distict stock keeping location)

The exact field to be updated is determined from a select statment. Essentially

```
UPDATE stock SET FIELD1=FIELD1+NEW.stquantity, FIELD2=FIELD2-NEW.stquantity
```

**WHERE FIELD1 and FIELD2 are determined by the case statement**

The trigger I have looks like this now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `changestockqty` AFTER INSERT ON `stocktransfer_items` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE fromstocklocationvar INT DEFAULT -1;
DECLARE tostocklocationvar INT DEFAULT -1;


SET fromstocklocationvar = (SELECT stsource_location FROM stocktransfers WHERE stocktransfer.idstocktransfers=NEW.idstocktransfers);
SET tostocklocationvar = (SELECT stdest_location FROM stocktransfers WHERE stocktransfer.idstocktransfers=NEW.idstocktransfers);

UPDATE stock SET
CASE
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5
END
=
CASE    
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4
WHEN fromstocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5
END
-NEW.stquantity,
CASE
WHEN tostocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1
WHEN tostocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2
WHEN tostocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3
WHEN tostocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4
WHEN tostocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5
END
=
CASE    
WHEN tostocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1
WHEN tostocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2
WHEN tostocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3
WHEN tostocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4
WHEN tostocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5
END
+NEW.stquantity,

 WHERE stock.idstockpcode=NEW.stpcode;

END
```

It shows an error after the first case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(

CASE

WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1

WHEN fromstocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2' at line 11

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a syntax error (you try to use CASE statements to create another statement)..

Try this SQL (does the same thing):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `changestockqty` AFTER INSERT ON `stocktransfer_items` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE fromstocklocationvar INT DEFAULT -1;
DECLARE tostocklocationvar INT DEFAULT -1;


SET fromstocklocationvar = (SELECT stsource_location FROM stocktransfers WHERE stocktransfer.idstocktransfers=NEW.idstocktransfers);
SET tostocklocationvar = (SELECT stdest_location FROM stocktransfers WHERE stocktransfer.idstocktransfers=NEW.idstocktransfers);

UPDATE stock SET
sl1 = CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1-NEW.stquantity ELSE sl1 END,
sl2 = CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2-NEW.stquantity ELSE sl2 END,
sl3 = CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3-NEW.stquantity ELSE sl3 END,
sl4 = CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4-NEW.stquantity ELSE sl4 END,
sl5 = CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5-NEW.stquantity ELSE sl5 END
,
sl1 = CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1+NEW.stquantity ELSE sl1 END,
sl2 = CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=2 THEN sl2+NEW.stquantity ELSE sl2 END,
sl3 = CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=3 THEN sl3+NEW.stquantity ELSE sl3 END,
sl4 = CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=4 THEN sl4+NEW.stquantity ELSE sl4 END,
sl5 = CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=5 THEN sl5+NEW.stquantity ELSE sl5 END

 WHERE stock.idstockpcode=NEW.stpcode;

END
```

Comment: I get the same error. ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE

WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN sl1=sl1-NEW.stquantity

WHEN fromstocklocat' at line 12

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. The left side of Update have to be fixed. 
Here is an example:

```
UPDATE stock SET
sl1=sl1 - CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=1 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=1 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END, 
sl2=sl2 - CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=2 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=2 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END, 
sl3=sl3 - CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=3 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=3 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END, 
sl4=sl4 - CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=4 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=4 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END, 
sl5=sl5 - CASE WHEN fromstocklocationvar=5 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN tostocklocationvar=5 THEN NEW.stquantity ELSE 0 END 

 WHERE stock.idstockpcode=NEW.stpcode;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it was not working (left side of update has to be fixed).